# How to make macro enabled Word document back into a normal word document?

Tags: microsoft-word

I have inherited some old Microsoft Word files which cannot be emailed as attachments because they are 'macro-enabled Word files' according to File Explorer.

How do I remove this classification to make the files back into 'normal' Word files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Open the file in Microsoft Word
2. Using 'Save As...' save the file as 'Word' format rather than 'macro-enabled Word File' format
3. Use the new file you have created with Save As from now on

Comment: Note, this will remove any macros that may be present in the document.